# In $SO(3)$, if the 3 Euler angles are given by $(\phi,\theta,-\phi)$, what is the resulting space named?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, quantum-mechanics

The space $SO(3)$ can be parameterized by 3 Euler angles $(\phi,\theta,\psi)$. If the 3 Euler angles are given by $(\phi,\theta,-\phi)$, what is the resulting space named?
The convention here is $R(\phi,\theta,\psi)=R_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)R_z(\psi)$, where $R_z(\phi)$ represents the rotation around $z$ axis etc.

Comment: What are the meanings of $\phi$, $\theta$, and $\psi$? I am asking because there are different conventions.

Comment: @timur: thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the space generated by these Euler angles when $\phi\in[0,2\pi), \theta\in[0,\pi)$ is a sphere with boundaries, since for any vector $x\in S^2$ the image under the rotation above is still $S^2$ minus a circle belonging to a plane containing $x$. This space looks like an open Poke-ball (the image attached has an exaggerated cutoff $\theta\in[0,\pi-0.05])$ and it has the topology of the complement of an annulus on a plane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do not quite understand why it is $S^2$ minus $S^1$ in a plane containing $x$ axis.

Comment: It's not the x axis, it's the arbitrary vector $x\in S^2$ that you chose to map under the Euler rotation prescribed.